# antlr4 - string escaping in literal

Tags: escaping, antlr, antlr4

I have the following rule:

```
value      : STRING;

STRING     : '"' ('\\"' | ~'"')* '"';
```

Is this a correct and smart way to allow the presence of `"` in a string? It is escaped as `\"`.

The string is parsed like this:

```
final ValueContext c = ...;
final String s = c.STRING().getText(); 

s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"");
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is how many other languages allow quotes to be escaped. Note that `~'"'` also allows line breaks to be included in your string literals. If you don't want that, replace it with `~["\r\n]`.